# Need optimize way to replace content of multiple input field with name attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to set input type value blank which i just passon name attribute.
for example

1) Multiline:

```
$('input[name="library"]').val('');
$('input[name="books"]').val('');
$('input[name="author"]').val('');
```

2) Single Line:

```
$('input[name="library"],input[name="books"],input[name="author"]').val('');
```

above both line is working for me. But I want more optimize way. Is there any way to write it like as follow

```
$('input[name="library"][name="books"][name="author"]').val('');
```

and it will blank all 3 input fields blank?

One more thing, I am getting these all input fields from other server, and I am not able to change input fields class on their server. So i just want to replace some of input fields on my side that i explain above.

Comment: show your markup.. so that we could think in different perspectives.

Comment: Something like `$(':input').filter('[name="library"][name="books"][name="author"]').val('');`?

Comment: @chridam Is that an optimized way.?

Comment: From the jQuery API documentation, `:input` is an extension that is not part of the CSS specification, queries using :input cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method but the best performance is achieved by first selecting the elements using a pure CSS selector, then using `.filter(":input")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array and function:

```
function inputEmpty( elem ) {
    $('input[name="'+elem+'"]').val('');
}

var names = [ "library", "books", "author" ];
names.forEach( inputEmpty );
```

Check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/nLm6u75z/

Answer (score 0):

You can group all your inputs with the same className like : "inputGroup".

The answer of your problem will be :

`$('.inputGroup').val('');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    $(this).val('My new value');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize the syntax a bit by removing 'input'; the [attr=val] syntax works by itself:

```
$('[name="library"],[name="books"],[name="author"]').val('');
```

Or are you looking for performance optimizations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `or`-like syntax in the jquery selectors then the answer is no, there is no `or` operator in the selectors.

Your last approach is the most concise way to select what you want without loosing any preciseness.

```
$('input[name="library"][name="books"][name="author"]').val('');
```

Answer (score -1):

Surely the easiest way to do this is to add a class to all three inputs then change their value based on that class as a selector?

```
<input type="text" name="library" class="input_change" />


$('.input_change').val('')
```

Comment: thanks, this one i know, but i am getting these all input fields from other server, and I am not able to change input fields class on their server. So i just want to replace some of input fields on my side that i explain

Comment: Ah okay. Edit your question to reflect this so other people don't get confused. :)